# Opengl-es 1.1 draw blur on model?

Tags: opengl-es

How can I draw blurred models/images in 3d space like here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is called Depth of Field effect. Here are few implementations in OpenGL:

- http://screamyguy.net/DepthOfField/
- http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch23.html
- http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=56